# How to encrypt SQlite database in Android using OpenSSL?

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption, openssl

I wanted to know how we can encrypt the Android SQlite database using OpenSSL?
Any samples or reference would help.

From what I read I got to know that we need to compile the OpenSSL source code :
[Reference link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/vDBdCra0QFA)

Not sure how to go about this ?

Thanks,
Nibs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to encrypt SQlite database in Android using OpenSSL?

Use [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/). It performs the encryption for you, and it uses OpenSSL as the underlying encryption library.

SQLCipher's description:

> SQLCipher is an open source extension to SQLite that provides
>   transparent 256-bit AES encryption of database files.

---

> From what I read I got to know that we need to compile the OpenSSL source code

Android already has OpenSSL installed. It usually a downlevel version (I think its 0.9.8), but it has everything you need for SQLCipher.

OpenSSL is loaded by Android's Zygote, so its already present in your application's address space. You don't even need to load it.

Comment: Thanks noloader for the great help.! Will use SQLCipher.